# Is there a way to reuse a DataSet in C#? I wanted to use the disconnected architecture

Tags: c#

I have a dataset which holds a table from DB already and i have to use this same dataset in a dropdown list event. 
However, I have an understanding of why the dataset is null before it arrives at the catch in my program. Besides establishing the new connection again in the *regionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged* event, is there an other way to rewrite? Below is my code. Thanks a lot:)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
       regionDropDown();
    }
}
DataSet mySet;
public void regionDropDown() {

    // Define ADO.NET objects.
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwindConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM Region", myConn);
        SqlDataAdapter daRegion = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dsRegion = new DataSet();
        daRegion.Fill(dsRegion, "Region");
        mySet = dsRegion;
        foreach (DataRow row in dsRegion.Tables["Region"].Rows)
        {
            ListItem ls = new ListItem();
            ls.Text = row["RegionID"].ToString();
            ls.Value = row["RegionID"].ToString();
            regionDropDownList.Items.Add(ls);

        }
    myConn.Close();
}

public void regionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        regionDropDown();

        foreach (DataRow row in mySet.Tables["Regions"].Rows)
        {
            if (regionDropDownList.SelectedValue == row["RegionID"].ToString())
            {
                regionDescriptionLabel.Text = row["RegionDescription"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { regionDescriptionLabel.Text = "Caught!!" + ex; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
       regionDropDown();
    }
}
DataSet mySet; // ?
public void regionDropDown() {

    // Define ADO.NET objects.
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwindConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM Region", myConn);
        SqlDataAdapter daRegion = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dsRegion = new DataSet();
        daRegion.Fill(dsRegion, "Region");
        mySet = dsRegion;

        // If you want,custom logic then you might use this code,
       // else just provide datatextfield and datavalue field before binding..
        foreach (DataRow row in dsRegion.Tables["Region"].Rows)
        {
            ListItem ls = new ListItem();
            ls.Text = row["RegionID"].ToString();
            ls.Value = row["RegionID"].ToString();
            regionDropDownList.Items.Add(ls);

        }
    myConn.Close();
}
```

Now in case of selectedindexchanged event ?

```
public void regionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        regionDropDown();

        foreach (DataRow row in mySet.Tables["Regions"].Rows)
        {
            if (regionDropDownList.SelectedValue == row["RegionID"].ToString())
            {
                regionDescriptionLabel.Text = row["RegionDescription"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { regionDescriptionLabel.Text = "Caught!!" + ex; }
}
```

Why calling again regionDropDown() here?

```
public void regionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

                regionDescriptionLabel.Text = regionDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text; // If value needed then regionDropDownList.SelectedValue

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I agree with the "DataSet mySet", I was testing and forgot to delete it. I had optimized the list in for loop now, thanks here. Also, just want to add, My table(Region) has RegionID, RegionDescription as columns. My case was to load the drop down list with the RegionIDs during page load and then when I choose an ID from drop down, it has to display the associated RegionDescription from Region Table.